# Is there an equivalent of submdspan for mdarray?

Tags: c++, std, c++-experimental, mdspan

[The repo of the exciting `mdspan`](https://github.com/kokkos/mdspan), a multi-dimensional analogue of `std::span` suggested for the C++ standard libraries, now also contains a reference implementation of the closely-related `mdarray`, which unlike `mdspan` owns its data.

But whereas the `submdspan` function can produce a subset of an `mdspan`, I can't find an analogue for `mdarray`. What I was expecting was a function that behaves exactly the same as `submdspan` and returns an `mdspan`, but which operates on an `mdarray`.

Is this planned but not implemented yet? If not, why not?

Edit:

I've temporarily solved it with a home-brew solution in the form of an overload of `submdspan` that takes an `mdarray`, then creates a temporary `mdspan` that maps to the entire `mdarray`, and calls `submdspan` on that.

It does the job for now! But I'm not confident this covers every conceivable `mdarray`, as there is almost no documentation at the moment. Would still love an answer to the original question.

```
template <class ElementType, class Extents, class LayoutPolicy, class... SliceSpecs>
auto submdspan(
    mdarray<ElementType, Extents, LayoutPolicy> &arr, 
    SliceSpecs... slices)
{
    return submdspan(
        mdspan<ElementType, Extents, LayoutPolicy>(arr.data(), arr.mapping()), 
        slices...);
}
```

Comment: Why ask here? Ask the author of that repo.

Comment: @KamilCuk, because this seems like a mature proposal and likely to become part of the C++ standard AFAIK. Also, I don't know how to reach the author.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just randomly ran across this: since I am the primary author/maintainer on all involved things (`mdspan`, `mdarray`, `submdspan` and the reference implementation) yeah we can add that. And the way I would do that is actually calling the "to_mdspan" function of the `mdarray`, and call submdspan on that:

```
auto sub = submdspan(mda.to_mdspan(), slice_specifiers...);
```

In order for the two proposals to be independent I will keep that apart for now (unless LEWG tells me otherwise) and write a follow up paper which simply adds an overload to `submdspan` which does the above to forward to the overload taking an `mdspan`.

But generally: you can just open an issue on the repo to ask about proposal issues.